# Why does this bash -e and -L test not capture this link?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which is intended to be idempotent. It creates symlinks, and it should be okay if the links are already there.

Here's an extract

```
    L="/var/me/foo"
    if [[ -e "$L" ]] && ! [[ -L "$L" ]];
    then
        echo "$L exists but is not a link."
        exit 1;
    elif [[ -e "$L" ]] && [[ -L "$L" ]];
    then
        echo "$L exists and is a link."
    else
        ln -s "/other/place" "$L" ||
        {
            echo "Could not chown ln -s for $L";
            exit 1;
        }
    fi
```

The file `/var/me/foo` is already a symlink pointing to `/other/place`, according to `ls -l`.

Nevertheless, when I run this script the `if` and `elif` branches are *not* entered, instead we go into the `else` and attempt the `ln`, which fails because the file already exists.

Why do my tests not work?

Comment: Could you create an example that can be run in a temporary directory (or even uses `mktemp -d` to create a directory on its own), so folks can copy/paste and run it without needing to change the names or have root privileges?

Comment: Also: Does `/other/place` exist? If it should, make sure that your example actually creates it (of course, under your temporary directory).

Comment: ...also, why do you only check `-L` if `-e` is true?

Comment: ...as an aside: All-caps variable names are used by variables with meaning to the shell or operating system. Consider using lowercase names for your own variables, which are reserved for application use, to avoid overwriting something important by mistake. See [the relevant POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) -- speaking to environment variables, but those conventions apply to regular shell variables as well since setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you only check `[ -L "$L" ]` if `[ -e "$L" ]` is true, and `[ -e "$L" ]` returns false for a link pointing to a destination that doesn't exist, you don't detect links that point to locations that don't exist.

The below logic is a bit more comprehensive.

```
link=/var/me/foo
dest=/other/place
# because [[ ]] is in use, quotes are not mandatory
if [[ -L $link ]]; then
  echo "$link exists as a link, though its target may or may not exist" >&2
elif [[ -e $link ]]; then
  echo "$link exists but is not a link" >&2
  exit 1
else
  ln -s "$dest" "$link" || { echo "yadda yadda" >&2; exit 1; }
fi
```